# Remove duplicate lines with position delimiter

Tags: javascript

I need a function javascript.
I have a list with format

```
abc|a|1
abc|a|2
abcd|a|1
abc|b|1
```

And i want to duplicate by first and second postion (split "|")
New list is:

```
abc|a|1
abcd|a|1
abc|b|1
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, your "i want to duplicate by" is unclear.  Are you saying that you want to produce the second list by leaving out "abc|a|2" from the first list?  And what *exact* rule do you want to use to identify want should be left out?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for my english. I want to duplicate by position 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the data with [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and take a temporary object for lookup if there is already an item with the same two parts in the result.

```js
var list = ['abc|a|1', 'abc|a|2', 'abcd|a|1', 'abc|b|1'],
    result = list.filter(function (a) {
        var b = a.split('|'), 
            k = b[0] + '|' + b[1];
        if (!this[k]) {
            this[k] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```